# Send report after Android JNI signal/exception

Tags: android, c++, firebase, java-native-interface, signals

I am trying to get firebase working with my Android app but it is mainly C++ code. 
A lot of chances are that if there is any crash it will be some kind of bad access in the C++ part. 
Firebase works well with uncaught java exceptions however I cannot get it to work with JNI signals/exceptions.

As far as I know it is not yet compatible with JNI but I thought a workaround would be something similar to this:

Somewehre in the C++ add a signal handler for signals we would like to handle that will send it back to the Java side and try to send a report ( with part of the stacktrace if possible ).

```
#include <cisgnal>
namespace
{
    void SignalHandler( int sig )
    {
         // Code to call a static method in my Activity
    }
}

CrashReporter::CrashReporter()
{
    ::signal( SIGABRT, & ::SignalHandler )
}

// In java
public static void SendReportOnCrash()
{
     FirebaseCrash.report( new Exception( "OOPS" ) );
}
```

Unfortunately, fake reports are never sent, however I do get callback in Java.
I tried to launch a process separated activity in which I would call FirebaseCrash.report() but there is no non-static way to it therefore it always crash since FirebaseApp/Crash are not instantiated in secondary activity.

I come here to ask if someone would have a hint on how to do that.

My last try but least wanted test would be to write the stack trace to a file, and upon a new start, test if this file exists, if so use FirebaseCrash.log then send a fake report...

Answer (score 0):

You are not guaranteed to be able to do any Java processing after the JVM calls `abort()` for a fatal error.  Per [the Java documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html):

> `SIGABRT`
>
> The HotSpot VM does not handle this signal. Instead it calls the abort
>   function after fatal error handling. If an application uses this
>   signal then it should terminate the process to preserve the expected
>   semantics.

Yes, that is for the Oracle implementation.  It quite likely applies to all other implementations also.

Because at the point it calls `abort()`, the JVM expects to be killed.